# Bash - find matching pairs of files

Tags: bash, file, find

I have many files in the folder:

```
Filename1.mp4
Filename2.mp4
Filename3.mp4
Etc.
```

As well as many files with added suffix to the name:

```
Filename1_x264.mp4
Filename2_x264.mp4
Filename3_x264.mp4
Etc.
```

I am trying to catch the matching pairs using `find` command and execute an external command on them but can't figure out a way to do it yet.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash and its Parameter Expansion:

```
for i in *_x264.mp4; do 
  j="${i%*_x264.mp4}.mp4"         # remove suffix _x264.mp4 and add .mp4
  if [[ -e "$j" ]]; then
    echo "$i and $j exists"
  fi
done
```

Comment: `-e "$i"` should always be true and can be neglected.

Comment: `-e "$i"` is always true if the pattern matches anything :) Using `shopt -s nullgob` or adding `[[ -e $i ]] || break` as the first line of the loop fixes that small corner case.

Comment: @chepner: Thank you. That should be considered.

Comment: Thank you @Cyrus, chepner and Socowi. It worked like a charm